# Why does nesting Civi shortcodes in Wordpress pages prevent Javascript files from loading?

Tags: javascript, html

If I create a new page and include this shortcode, the Civi User Dashboard displays correctly.

```
[civicrm component="user-dashboard"]
```

If I create a new page but nest the same short code inside of an outer shortcode, several JS files do not get loaded. A section titled "<!-- CiviCRM html header -->" (present in non-nested output) does not output.

```
[members_logged_in]
[civicrm component="user-dashboard"]
[/members_logged_in]
```

Comment: Huh, I just thought it was the plugin I was using (Groups). Good to know it is all of them.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_shortcode_regex/

"get_shortcode_regex" doesn't seem to work when nesting CiviCRM shortcodes. I found 2 hacky workarounds.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your hacky workarounds ?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using page tags to tell a php script which pages need to force CiviCRM resources to load.

```
if ( function_exists('has_tag') && function_exists('get_the_id') && has_tag('logged-in-no-cache', get_the_id()) ) {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( civi_wp(), 'front_end_page_load' ), 100 );
}
```

This goes in functions.php.

Comment: @samuelsov here's what I've come up with.

Comment: awesome, it's perfect for my needs